# Angular switch Outer Div based on boolean

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.4.7 and need to do the following

```
<div ng-if="varIsTrue">
<div ng-if="!(varIsTrue)" my-custom-directive>
  A lot of content
</div>
```

So basically, if the div is set only the proper div shows up. I tried do a few variations of this with ng-if and ng-show but I believe because how the browser renders the dom it is messing it up with the multiple divs, but that is the concept I am going for. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Can you create a plunker? Normally this would work, if you have ngAnimate included it can cause "funnies" like this as items arent removed instantly. Edit - I think animations are included by default now, check there is no transition CSS on those divs

Comment: Oh Interesting I didn't realize it should work, I may have done something wrong and just assumed it wasn't working. If I cannot get it I will create a plunkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this you should have 2 closing tags

```
<div ng-if="varIsTrue">
</div>
<div ng-if="!(varIsTrue)" my-custom-directive>
  A lot of content
</div>
```

or you will have  to switch in my-custom-directive

Comment: But one closing tag should work? Maybe I did something wrong I will try again

Comment: no it should not work, the ng-if is applied to <div></div> not only the opening tag

Comment: So is there no way to get it to work with one div? That is my original question